# Distinguishing between chaos and multiperiodic oscillations from the Fourier spectrum

Tags: fourier-analysis, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider a system which exhibits multiperiodicity, say with oscillations of the form

$$x(t) = \sum_{n=0} c_n \cos(n \omega_0 t), \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$$

The Fourier transform $\tilde{x}(\omega)$ will then contain peaks at $n \omega_0$ with strength proportional to $c_n$ (for simplicity, we can add a small decaying factor $e^{-\gamma t}$ to $x(t)$ to avoid delta-functions).

Restricting to deterministic systems, chaos appears as a continuous Fourier spectrum (as opposed to a line spectra). In our example, suppose the Fourier peaks are governed by some continuous envelope function $f(\omega)$ such that $\tilde{x}(n \omega_0) = f(n\omega_0)$. In the limit of $\omega_0 \to 0$, the peaks become infinitesimally close. Can this then be interpreted as a chaotic motion?

Comment: Could you please state more precisely what you mean by "(for simplicity, we can add a small decaying factor $e^{−γ t}$ to $x(t)$ to avoid delta-functions)"? Are you implying $f(t)=x(t)+e^{−γ t}$ avoids delta functions?

Comment: I meant multiplying by an exponentially decaying factor so that the Fourier transform consists of a set of peaks with a finite width

Comment: Multiplying by $e^{-\gamma  t}$ only causes a frequency shift in the result (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Modulation_/_frequency_shifting).

Comment: Perhaps multiplying $x(t)$ by  the factor $e^{-\gamma\,  t^2}$ achieves your desired result.